# Incorrect tax calculation. Magento adding extra penny on Order Totals

Tags: magento

One of my clients got back to me recently saying that magento is adding an extra penny in Total amount of order.

It looks like it might be a Magento tax calculation which is out as it is calculating the actual value of the product to be £33.32 where the full price is £39.99 and tax at £6.67. However on the order totals, it looks like it makes the actual value £33.33 net and vat £6.67 which comes to total of £40?

I have also attached a screen shoot to make it clearer.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to

Issue on bugtracker
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=12244

Theme on magentocommerce.com forum
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/247201/#t346936